# Easily serialize an object to JSON

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

How do I serialize an Swift object to JSON, the following object for example :

```
class Order {

   var id:Int
   var title:String
   var email:String

   init(id:Int, title:String, email:String) {
      self.id = id
      self.title = title
      self.email = email
   }
}

let order = Order(id:345, title:"Title", email:"email@gmail.com")
```

Currently I tried creating a SwiftyJSON `JSON` object like so but it still requires me to manually specify each property :

```
let json = JSON()
json["id"] = order.id
json["title"] = order.title
json["email"] = order.email
```

Moreover, that doesn't help me as Alamofire doesn't understand SwiftyJSON's objects, requiring me to create a dictionary manually :

```
let dict:[String, AnyObject] = [
    "id":order.id,
    "title":order.title,
    "email":order.email
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, Configuration.ADD_ORDER_URL, parameters: dict, encoding:.JSON)
```

To recap, how can I serialize an object to JSON and send it off right away using Alamofire ?

Comment: Take a look at [this code](https://gist.github.com/anaimi/ad336b44d718430195f8), it may help you about serializing the object to JSON.

Comment: I've edited your question to be a bit more clear, feel free to rollback the edit if you disagree.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but and it took me way too long to find this out.

However, user2629998's response is correct. In the OP's case he is using a dictionary so he needs to declare like so:

`let parameters:[String : AnyObject] = []`

Also, you have to declare the header

`let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]`

which later must be passed to the alamofire request

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, yourEndpoint, headers:headers, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
```

I decided to elaborate more on user2629998 because the header can make a difference.

Also, I wanted to point out that this can be non-intuitive for many users as I noticed when searching through different questions regarding this issue or similar problems. Why? because even when you want to send a JSON, you can not do that in Alamofire. So basically, Alamofire takes care of it under the hood. Hence, you're are forced to send the dictionary and make use of Alamofire's neat features.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Alamofire documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#post-request-with-json-encoded-parameters) :

```
let parameters = [
    "foo": [1,2,3],
    "bar": [
        "baz": "qux"
    ]
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
```

You create an array representing your JSON, and then set the `encoding` argument to `Alamofire.JSON`. SwiftyJSON has nothing to do here, as it only deals with deserializing a JSON response.